# How can I return a calloc pointer from C into C++?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I am working on a personal project that requires me to call C functions from C++ code. These C functions return a calloc() pointer.

1t5.h

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * prob1(char * number);
```

1t5.c

```c
#include <1t5.h>

char * prob1(char * number) {
    int ni = atoi(number);
    char prompt[] = "hello\n";
    char * answer = (char*)calloc(ni, sizeof(prompt));
    for (int i = 0; i < ni; i++) {
        strcat(*answer, prompt);
    }
    return answer;
}
```

That C code is supposed to return a given number of "hello\n".

linking.cpp

```cpp
string Link::problemRouting(string problem, vector<string> contents) {
    string answers = "";
    char * ca;

    int pi = stoi(problem);

    for (int i = 0; i < contents.size(); i++) {
        ca = cv.stringToChar(contents[i]);
        // C Standard
        if (pi <= 5) {
            char * answer;
            switch(pi) {
                case 1:{
                    answer = prob1(ca);
                }
                case 2: {
                    answer = prob2(ca);
                }
                case 3: {
                    answer = prob3(ca);
                }
                case 4: {
                    answer = prob4(ca);
                }
                case 5: {
                    answer = prob5(ca);
                }
            }

            cout << answer;
            answers+=answer;
            free(answer);
        }
    }

    return answers;
}
```

This C++ code takes the return value and saves it to store into a text file later.

The problem is when I input a number, lets say `257`, then the return value is `257`, and not a ton of `"hello\n"`.

Comment: yes, just make sure you use free, not delete on thm

Comment: I did use free on them? When I comment out the free, the issue still remains.

Comment: `strcat(*answer, prompt);` should be `strcat(answer, prompt);`

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings.  You should see something like "trying to create pointer from int".  That invariably informs you that you're doing something bad.

Comment: ah, i missed that you had a problem, I thought it was a general question of 'is this ok to mix'

Comment: The *answer was something I tried to test to see if it would work or not, and it didn't.

Comment: Your C++ `switch` is missing a `break` statement on each `case`, so you are going to cause fallthrough leading to memory leaks. `cv.stringToChar()` also looks like another potential memory leak, who is managing the memory for the returned `char*`?

Comment: Don't vandalize your own posts. Your question is meaningless without the probem you are asking about.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to @Remy Lebeau for the answer.

My code contained many chances for memory to leak, resulting in a mess of a return value.

```
string Link::problemRouting(string problem, vector<string> contents) {
string answers = "";
char * ca;

int pi = stoi(problem);

for (int i = 0; i < contents.size(); i++) {
    ca = cv.stringToChar(contents[i]);
    // C Standard
    if (pi <= 5) {
        char * answer;
        switch(pi) {
            case 1:{
                answer = prob1(ca);
                break;
            }
        }
        free(ca);
        cout << answer;
        answers+=answer;
        free(answer);
    }
}

return answers;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).